# UIPickerView selectRow not changing display

Tags: ios, uipickerview

I have done many picker views before, some with 2 components. But after reading all the articles before I can't get a row to be selected.

I have 2 picker views on a scrollview within my view controller. Each with a different tag and different values. The pickers are loading correctly so I now the delegate and data source are working.

I have a number of switches on the same view and they are updating correctly.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *autolockPicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *autoRelockPicker;

 autolockTimes = @[@"Disabled",@"5 Seconds",@"10 Seconds",@"15 Seconds",@"30 Seconds"];
autolockPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
autolockPicker.delegate = self;
autolockPicker.tag = 0;

autoRelockTimes = @[@"Disabled",@"15 Seconds",@"30 Seconds",@"60 Seconds",@"90 Seconds"];
autoRelockPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];
autoRelockPicker.delegate = self;
autoRelockPicker.tag = 1;

 if ([lsd.ARE isEqualToString:@"Disabled"]) {
    [autoRelockPicker selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
} else if ([lsd.ART isEqualToString:@"15"]) {
    [autoRelockPicker selectRow:1 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
} else if ([lsd.ART isEqualToString:@"30"]) {
    NSLog(@"ART is 30");
    [autoRelockPicker selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
} else if ([lsd.ART isEqualToString:@"60"]) {
    NSLog(@"ART is 60");
    [autoRelockPicker selectRow:3 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
} else if ([lsd.ART isEqualToString:@"90"]) {
    [autoRelockPicker selectRow:4 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
}
```

I get the NSLog for ART is 30, so I know I'm there.

I've tried :
- reloading the component before and after
- triggering didSelectRow
- loading from ViewWillAppear
- creating an Button to update the desired row

nothing has worked.

Thanks!

Comment: Curious - if your picker view properties are setup as outlets, why do you also create the picker view programmatically?

Comment: There is no context in your question. Where is all of this code? What is the actual problem? It's not clear.

Comment: maddy. You're a genius. I've been looking at it for so long. I had of course borrowed code from one of my other apps. I just commented out the alloc and it works!

Comment: @maddy how do I up vote your answer?

Comment: I didn't post an answer. I asked you a question. Feel free to either delete your question or post your own proper answer clearly explaining what the issue was and how you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @maddy, I realized I was allocating the picker programmatically. I removed the lines to alloc and init the pickers and it worked!